# Export all charts as graphics

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a way to easily export all charts from a workbook in Excel as graphics. I have the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportChart()
     '   Export a selected chart as a picture
    Const sSlash$ = "/"
    Const sPicType$ = ".png"
    Dim sChartName$
    Dim sPath$
    Dim sBook$
    Dim objChart As ChartObject


    On Error Resume Next
     '   Test if there are even any embedded charts on the activesheet
     '   If not, let the user know
    Set objChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    If objChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No charts have been detected on this sheet", 0
    Exit Sub
    End If


     '   Test if there is a single chart selected
    If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "You must select a single chart for exporting ", 0
    Exit Sub
    End If


Start:
    sChartName = Application.InputBox("Please Specify a name for the exported chart" & vbCr & _
    "There is no default name available" & vbCr & _
    "The chart will be saved in the same folder as this file", "Chart Export", "")

     '   User presses "OK" without entering a name
    If sChartName = Empty Then
    MsgBox "You have not entered a name for this chart", , "Invalid Entry"
    GoTo Start
    End If

     '   Test for Cancel button
    If sChartName = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

     '   If a name was given, chart is exported as a picture in the same
     '   folder location as their current file
    sBook = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    sPath = sBook & sSlash & sChartName & sPicType
    ActiveChart.Export Filename:=sPath, FilterName:="PNG"

End Sub
```

This will export the active chart, but how can I export all charts? Bonus points if the charts are named after the worksheet they came from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Sub Test()

Dim sht As Worksheet, cht As ChartObject
Dim x As Integer

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        x = 1
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            cht.Chart.Export "C:\local files\temp\" & sht.Name _
                              & "_" & x & ".png", "PNG"
            x = x + 1
        Next cht

    Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the rationale for the "_1" in the filename?

Comment: If there are more than one chart on a sheet you can't give them the same file name...  It wasn't clear from your question how many charts you had.

Comment: Just one chart per sheet in this case, but good call. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's important to note that there is a bug in Excel VBA that causes 0-byte files to be randomly produced. Including cht.Activate before the Export resolves the issue. For reference: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/808744-exporting-chart-via-visual-basic-applications-sometimes-gives-empty-file.html

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty.
You want to put this at the bottom of you code to loop through worksheets and all chart objects on each sheet.

I did not test this as I don't have time to recreate your files or situation.
Hope this helps

```
For each x in worksheets.count then
  For Each objChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects then
    sChartName = activesheet.name
    sBook = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    sPath = sBook & sSlash & sChartName & sPicType
    ActiveChart.Export Filename:=sPath, FilterName:="PNG"
  Next objChart
Next x
```